# Location of .net TBB dll's on the CM server?

Tags: 2013, templating

Where is the location of .net TBB dll's on the CM server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not stored on the CM server.

When you upload a .Net Assembly TBB it is uploaded to a temporary directory on the server and then the Assembly is stored as binary data in the Content Manager database.

This is why, if you run a scaled system (i.e multiple Content Managers, separate Publishers) you do not need to deploy your Assembly TBBs to all of those systems.

I assume that during templating they are retrieved from the database and loaded into the .Net runtime dynamically.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get the DLL by exporting the TBB via Content Porter.  The DLL was in the export package.

Comment: If you need to get hold of the DLLs you can open Assembly TBBs in the CME. In the source tab there's a _Save to Disk_ option, just like a Multimedia component. Slightly easier than Content Porter! ;) They're also available through WebDAV (with a .tbbasm file extension) and through Core Service